# expected value product dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

My question is strictly operative, if I have, for instance, two random variables $X$ and $Y$, $X$ is a $\mathcal{N}(m,\sigma^2)$ and $Y=e^{h(X-m)-1/2(h^2\sigma^2)}$.

$E[Ye^X]$ is $\int y e^x p(x) dx$, isn't it?

Sorry but I can't find an unambiguous answer, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's about right.   The convention is to use capital letters for the random variables themself, and lowercase for values they take in particular instances; such as the parameters in the integral.

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{\bf E}[Y{\bf e}^X] & = \int_{\bf \Omega} y\; {\bf e}^x \, {p}_{_X}(x) \operatorname{d} x\qquad:\quad y={\bf e}^{h(x-m)-1/2(h^2\sigma^2)}
\\[1ex]& = \int_{\bf \Omega} \frac{{\bf e}^{h(x-m)-1/2(h^2\sigma^2) + x -(x-m)^2/2\sigma^2}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \operatorname{d}x
\end{align}$$

Comment: notation fixed, really thanks